# laravel pivot table with additional parameters

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm building a laravel app that tracks projects. A user can define tasks and attach them to projects.

I'd like the user to be able to have a list of tasks that can be re-used for multiple projects. This is simple enough using a pivot table that links projects and tasks:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('project_task', function($table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id');
        $table->integer('task_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

However, I'd like the user to be able to set different due dates for tasks depending on the project. So on project 1, Task A is due in one week. On project 2, Task A is due in a month.

What's the best table schema to store these type of values? Does there need to be another pivot table that links the task parameters to the project ID? I'm not sure how to handle this.

Thanks for your input.

EDIT: I'm using the Eloquent ORM, so the pivot rows are never really exposed, it just grabs the `Task` object associated with the `Project`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add `due_date` field to the `project_task` table. So in total you will have three tables project, task and project_task (which you have in your question)

Like this you will define the `task` once and can assign different due date for each project

**Edit**

You can define a custom pivot model that includes the `due_date` see [Defining A Custom Pivot Model](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

Comment: @iTech-- I considered that but due to the relations defined at the model level, when you use the Eloquent system it never really pulls in the pivot data-- it grabs the object that the pivot table is pointing to, that is, the actual `Task` rather than the `project_task` row.